# Will using an indexed view improve performance of SELECT COUNT queries?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexed-view

I have a table with that will grow to several million rows over some years.  As part of my web application, I have to query the count on a subset of this table whenever a user accesses a particular page.  Someone with an architecty hat has said that they have a performance concern with that.  Assuming they are correct, will adding an indexed view address this issue?

Sql that I want to be fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Txxx] WHERE SomeName = 'ZZZZ'
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM [dbo].[Txxx] WHERE SomeName = 'ZZZZ'
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Txxx](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [SomeName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SomeGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Txxx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

View:

```
CREATE view dbo.Vxxx
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT     SomeName, COUNT_BIG(*) AS UsedCount
FROM         dbo.Txxx
GROUP BY SomeName
```

Index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IV_COUNT] ON [dbo].[Vxxx] 
(
    [SomeName] ASC
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only Enterprise Edition will consider the indexed view during query compilation. To leverage the index on non-EE you need to select directly from the view and use the [NOEXPAND hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

> NOEXPAND applies only to indexed views. An indexed view is a view with
>   a unique clustered index created on it. If a query contains references
>   to columns that are present both in an indexed view and base tables,
>   and the query optimizer determines that using the indexed view
>   provides the best method for executing the query, the query optimizer
>   uses the index on the view. This function is called indexed view
>   matching. **Automatic use of indexed view by query optimizer is
>   supported only in specific editions of SQL Server**.

Be warned that a indexed view like this will create write contention, because any update will lock and entire `SomeName` scope: only one transaction at a time will be able to insert, delete or update any row with `SomeName = 'ZZZZ'`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I want to accept it, but I'm worried by the fact that the count is not actually part of the index, so the documentation does not really cover this scenario.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I created some test data, but was unable to confirm the answer because it turns out all the SQL boxes here are SQL Standard.   I did confirm that I have to use NOEXPAND and query the view directly in my scenario.  Marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that indexed view will definitely improve the performance of that particular query (assuming Enterprise Edition - Remus explains how to utilize it if you're not on Enterprise).

However, it isn't "free" - the index will need to be maintained for all DML operations to `dbo.Txxx`, will occupy space (though considerably less than the base table, in comparison), and will be subject to issues that also affect normal tables - such as fragmentation and (likely to a lesser extent in this case) page splits.